# Events emitted from slotted components

Tags: svelte

I try to wrap an application into a 'Repository' component and that outer component should handle all communication with the backend, like loading, updating, deleting editable data. I thought I could just send events up to that `Repository` component but I doesn't work the way I do it. Does anyone spot the issue or can explain, why this doesn't work and how to do it correctly with events? I could use writables instead but events would make it more readable. Here's a simplified example and a svelte REPL link:

https://svelte.dev/repl/e1eae56c7d5e48b2a99299f1bc1bf970?version=3.22.3

App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Repository from './Repository.svelte'
    import Application from './Application.svelte'
</script>

<Repository>
    <Application on:save={() => console.log('caught in App')} />
</Repository>
```

Repository.svelte:

```
<div on:save={() => console.log('caught in Repository')}>
    <slot></slot>
</div>
```

Application.svelte:

```
<script>
    import {createEventDispatcher} from 'svelte'

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    function saveHandler() {
        console.log('dispatching')
        dispatch('save')
    }

</script>

<button on:click={saveHandler}>
    Save
</button>
```

The desired output would be

```
dispatching
caught in Repository
```

but it only prints

```
dispatching
caught in App
```

when the button is clicked.

Comment: If `<Application>` is always a descendant of `<Repository>`, then this might be a good use case for the [context API](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/context-api) — it allows the two components to communicate with each other without the app developer needing to manually wire them up with event handlers etc.

Comment: It is. The repository can create a context with all repository methods (CRUD) and I can stop sending and converting all those custom events. Never used it but it looks as it will solve my problems in a very elegant way.

Comment: It sounds like you’re looking for [event forwarding](https://svelte.dev/docs#on_component_event).

Comment: @JustinMakeig That's what I use already. But it started getting very ugly. I found myself forwarding events through many layers and even writing handlers only to dispatch the same value with a different event name.

Comment: This will be addressed in Svelte 5 by providing the option to forward ALL events with a simple syntax.

Answer (score 8):

Found at least one solution, the `let` directive can help, although it's no pure eventing and pretty verbose.

https://svelte.dev/repl/a03214d522cd4bcba67f86c426a3b28d?version=3.22.3

App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Repository from './Repository.svelte'
    import Application from './Application.svelte'
</script>

<Repository let:saveHandler={saveHandler}>
    <Application on:save={saveHandler} />
</Repository>
```

Repository.svelte:

```
<script>
    function saveHandler() {
        console.log('caught in Repository')
    }
</script>

<div>
    <slot {saveHandler}></slot>
</div>
```

Application.svelte:

```
<script>
    import {createEventDispatcher} from 'svelte'

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    function saveHandler() {
        console.log('dispatching')
        dispatch('save')
    }

</script>

<button on:click={saveHandler}>
    Save
</button>
```

The con (or pro) is that we have to expose all methods from the Repository with `let` directives on the main component and also catch the events there, which can be a lot of unwanted event forwarding (because events only bubble up one level).

Answer (score 3):

### Svelte Events do not Bubble but HTML Events do

The cleanest solution I have found is to use HTML-Events instead of Svelte dispatched events. HTML Events can bubble up through the DOM and can be catched by parent components.

On the child:

```
node.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('save', { bubbles: true }))
```

On the parent:

```
node.addEventListener('save', saveHandler)
```

Svelte REPL with example:
https://svelte.dev/repl/b5f5e41bae704e6a83fc0cf8c0f58f57